Issue running nginx and apache on EC2 instance
I have a website running on Apache on EC2 Ubuntu instance.
Now I wanted to install "n8n" and was following a tutorial that required nginx. So I installed nginx and becuase apache was running on port 80, i configured nginx to run on port 8080.
This is what I did.
First, I edited the nginx.conf file (Certbot certificate was added later).
My n8n instance runs on port 5678.
server {
listen 8080;
server_name sub.domain.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5678;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_cache off;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

Then I also edited the default file to add the port number:
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    listen [::]:8080 default_server;

If I run nginx -t I get this:
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

But when I try to run the server, I get this error:
2024/04/03 22:31:49 [emerg] 13119#13119: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2024/04/03 22:31:49 [emerg] 13119#13119: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2024/04/03 22:31:49 [emerg] 13119#13119: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown 
error)
2024/04/03 22:31:49 [emerg] 13119#13119: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2024/04/03 22:31:49 [emerg] 13119#13119: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2024/04/03 22:31:49 [emerg] 13119#13119: still could not bind()

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?
Thanks

Issue seems to be with the listen 443 ssl of certbot. Your EC2 might be having something else listening on port 443. Could you check using sudo ps aux | grep ":443" ?

Thanks for your note. WHen I run that, I get this:
root       13356  0.0  0.2   7016  2304 pts/0    S+   23:52   0:00 grep --color=auto :443
